# How to preserve the transparent background of a report after it is rendered as an image?

Tags: c#, image, reporting-services, report, rdlc

I'm currently using this code to generate my charts to `.PNG` using `.RDLC` templates.

```
string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" + "<OutputFormat>PNG</OutputFormat>" + "</DeviceInfo>";
//rpv is an instance of Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer class defined in code-behind
byte[] bytes = rpv.LocalReport.Render("Image",deviceInfo, out mimeType, out enc,out ext, out strmid, out wrngs);

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(imagePath + "." + filenameExtension, FileMode.Create))
{
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

The report is rendered in `.PNG` format which supports transparency. However, I noticed that the report's background transparency is not preserved even though I have set the `BackgroundColor` to `No Color` in the report designer

[image]

---

How to preserve the transparency of rdlc reports when it is rendered as an image?

Comment: Here's a suggestion : set the `BackgroundColor` of the report to any Color, Let's say `Red`,  then set `report1.TransparencyKey = Color.Red;` This might work for you. I believe the alpha channel for transparency is not getting preserved. But anyway try this. Just include these Colors in the constructor of the report

Comment: @Nobody `TransparencyKey` is only available on `System.Windows.Forms`... I'm using `ReportViewer` to generate the reports as image.

Comment: Quickest way to find out that is *not* what you want is to use Bitmap.MakeTransparent() afterwards.  Text requires a known background so the anti-aliasing pixels have the correct color.

Comment: did u find a solution?

Comment: @Leandro Nope. I ended up using a third-party tool to remove the white background after I have generated the image.